# Hide/Show table columns depending on the element clicked

Tags: javascript

I would like to create some type of buttons that would only show the table columns affected to them and hidding every others, and add/remove the active class to the buttons, for example:

```
<a href="#" class="btn active" id="fruits">Data 1</a>
<a href="#" class="btn" id="vegetables">Data 2</a>
<a href="#" class="btn" id="nuts">Data 3</a>

<table>

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="fruits">First column</th>
            <th class="vegetables">Second column</th>
            <th class="nuts">Third column</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="fruits">Test 1</td>
            <td class="vegetables">Test 2</td>
            <td class="nuts">Test 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

For example, when I click on the "**Data 2**" button, it adds the "**active**" class to it, hides every other columns and only shows the items having the class called "**vegetables**".

I am a beginner and I would like to know if that's possible and how? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Looks like your question is answered but I'd like to add a little extra semantic HTML advice. You should only use anchor tags when they need to open a new URL (that's what the href is for) if there's no external link or meaningful href attribute to put in there you should be using the <button> element.

Comment: @JHeth Didn't know, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make a column active, you need to figure out the index of the clicked button. After that, you can iterate through the headers and columns to figure out which ones to show or hide.

The example below will only show the clicked column (`th` and `td`) of the clicked button.

**Update:** If you want to show/hide based on the field that was clicked, you can reference the button id and target the class of each table cell.

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.buttons a')).forEach(a => {
  a.addEventListener('click', handleButtonClick);
});

function handleButtonClick(e) {
  let selectedId = e.target.id;
  document.querySelectorAll('.buttons a').forEach((a) => {
    a.classList[a.id === selectedId ? 'add' : 'remove']('active');
  });
  document.querySelectorAll('table > thead > tr th').forEach(th => {
    th.style.display = th.classList.contains(selectedId) ? 'table-cell' : 'none';
  });
  document.querySelectorAll('table > tbody > tr td').forEach(td => {
    td.style.display = td.classList.contains(selectedId) ? 'table-cell' : 'none';
  });
};
```

```css
.buttons a {
  display: inline-block;
  border: thin solid grey;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #AAA;
}
.buttons a.active {
  background: #FFF;
}
table, th, td {
  border: thin solid grey;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
th, td {
  padding: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <a href="#" class="btn active" id="fruits">Fruits</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn" id="vegetables">Vegetables</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn" id="nuts">Nuts</a>
</div>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="fruits">Fruits</th>
      <th class="vegetables">Vegetables</th>
      <th class="nuts">Nuts</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="fruits">Apple</td>
      <td class="vegetables">Artichoke</td>
      <td class="nuts">Almond</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="fruits">Banana</td>
      <td class="vegetables">Broccoli</td>
      <td class="nuts">Brazil Nut</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="fruits">Cherry</td>
      <td class="vegetables">Carrot</td>
      <td class="nuts">Cashew</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this suits you.
*Some tweaks may be needed if you'll need extra classes on the `<table>`*

```js
$(() => { // wait until DOM is ready
  $('.btn').click(function onclick() { // set up onclick handler for all buttons of class 'btn'
    // on click
    $('.btn').removeClass('active');
        // remove 'active' class from all buttons
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
        // but add 'active' class to the clicked one (this)
    $('table').attr('class', $(this).attr('id'))
        // finally set the table class to be the id of the clicked button
  })
})
```

```css
a.active { color: green }
table .fruits     { display: none }
table .vegetables { display: none }
table .nuts       { display: none }

table.fruits     .fruits     { display: table-cell }
table.vegetables .vegetables { display: table-cell }
table.nuts       .nuts       { display: table-cell }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="btn" id="fruits"    >Data 1</a>
<a href="#" class="btn" id="vegetables">Data 2</a>
<a href="#" class="btn" id="nuts"      >Data 3</a>

<table>

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="fruits"    >First column</th>
            <th class="vegetables">Second column</th>
            <th class="nuts"      >Third column</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="fruits"    >Test 1</td>
            <td class="vegetables">Test 2</td>
            <td class="nuts"      >Test 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```